# Должна ли ставиться запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:

При размещении логотипа расстояния до края поверхности
или других графических элементов макета не должны быть меньше
указанных на рисунке.

Конструкция "при размещении логотипа расстрояния до края" звучит сложно и непонятно.
Считаю, что предложение должно выглядеть так:

При размещении логотипа, расстояния до края поверхности
или других графических элементов макета не должны быть меньше
указанных на рисунке.

По правилам ли это?

Answer (score 3):

1. Обособление предложно-падежных форм существительных  регулируется правилами Розенталя в теме  [Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114).

В общем случае обособление **факультативное**, но при этом для каждого случая требуется объяснение (см. правило).

2. В данном случае такое обособление обоснованным не кажется. Текст **специального** назначения с понятным для пользователя содержанием. При чтении делается обычная произносительная пауза, которая запятой не обозначается.

Для актуализации нераспространенного оборота в начале предложения  **нет причин** (даже графически это выглядит странно).

Comment: Тут обстоятельство не относится ко второй части высказывания. И ссылка не работает.

Comment: При размещении логотипа необходимо придерживаться следующих критериев: расстояния до края поверхности или других графических элементов макета не должны быть меньше указанных на рисунке.

Comment: Это детерминант, он относится ко всему сообщению. Вы увеличиваете объем текста, а насколько это необходимо? Больше слов, меньше информативности. Можете доказать, что предложенная запись некорректна по грамматике? И по поводу обособления оборота запятой тоже скажите. Такое обособление что-нибудь меняет?  Ну и контекст надо учитывать, от этого многое зависит.

Comment: Детерминант должен быть полноценным, а он ущербный, в этом проблема, хотя это основа высказывания, а вся правая часть - это всего лишь доп условие.

Comment: Без контекста с ущербностью детерминанта вряд ли разобраться.  И без автора текста – тоже)  К тому же в каждой теме своя фразеология, а единый канцелярский стиль не везде подходит.